# Calculating a metonic cycle

Tags: time-keeping

How one can calculate a [metonic cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonic_cycle) based on arbitrary values of the solar year length and the moon's orbital period?

I'm gathering information required for calendar-making, and right now I'm stuck with the above question. I need to calculate how long a metonic cycle lasts for a planet with a moon. It is required for making lunar and lunisolar calendars.

Comment: Might be worth linking to the definition of a metonic cycle, or summarising it, for the benefit of people unfamiliar with the subject.

Comment: Not certain where the question is going precisely, but observations - recorded observations over many, many decades(/centuries) - possibly by monks/scribes/royal astronomers. Patterns emerge from the data. Can you clarify in what sense you need to calculate - is yours a world with computers/satellite-telescopes etc., or more primitive?

Comment: @AngryMuppet Well I think I need to know only the case when given two numbers: a solar year in planets days and a moon's period (also in days) I want to calculate two other numbers that combined with the previous ones will give the same value. I don't care *how* my civilization got these two numbers (they can be pure wrong or inaccurate), I'm interested only in the math.

Comment: What is a metatonic cycle? How many wheels does it have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Iteration

Here on Earth, a year is ~365.2422 days and a month is ~29.5306 days.

To find the intersection, you list out multiples of each until they become sufficiently similar that they are approximately equal. They will never be exactly equal so, you need to decide how accurate you want to be by defining a margin to use as your stop point.  For example, the 19 year metonic cycle on Earth is only accurate to the day (actually within about 2.16hrs, but the ancient astronomers who first calculated it were probably looking for to the day), but if you want to be accurate to the hour, it is a 334 year cycle. To the minute it is every 20,401 years... so knowing your margin of error is important.

Below is a PHP script that does it using Earth based values.  Feel free to change the values in the function call to get other metonic cycles.

```
<?php
function getMetonicCycle($year, $month, $stopMargin){
    $thisMargin = abs($year - $month);
    $yearCount = 1; 
    $monthCount = 1;
    $monthDays = $month;
    $yearDays = $year;
    while ($thisMargin > $stopMargin){
        $monthCount ++;
        $monthDays = $month * $monthCount;
        $thisMargin = abs(($yearDays) - ($monthDays));
        if ($yearDays < $monthDays && $thisMargin > $stopMargin){
            $yearCount ++;
            $yearDays = $year * $yearCount;
        }
        echo ('Year = ' . $yearCount . ' ('. round($yearDays,4) . 'days) --- Month = ' . $monthCount . ' ('. round($monthDays,4) . 'days) --- Margin = '.round($thisMargin,2).'<br>');
    }
}
getMetonicCycle(365.2422, 29.53059, 1);
?>
```

This results in something like this where it iterates until the margin is smaller than 1 day.

```
Year = 1 (365.2422days) --- Month = 2 (59.0612days) --- Margin = 306.18
Year = 1 (365.2422days) --- Month = 3 (88.5918days) --- Margin = 276.65
Year = 1 (365.2422days) --- Month = 4 (118.1224days) --- Margin = 247.12
Year = 1 (365.2422days) --- Month = 5 (147.653days) --- Margin = 217.59
Year = 1 (365.2422days) --- Month = 6 (177.1835days) --- Margin = 188.06
Year = 1 (365.2422days) --- Month = 7 (206.7141days) --- Margin = 158.53
Year = 1 (365.2422days) --- Month = 8 (236.2447days) --- Margin = 129
Year = 1 (365.2422days) --- Month = 9 (265.7753days) --- Margin = 99.47
Year = 1 (365.2422days) --- Month = 10 (295.3059days) --- Margin = 69.94
Year = 1 (365.2422days) --- Month = 11 (324.8365days) --- Margin = 40.41
Year = 1 (365.2422days) --- Month = 12 (354.3671days) --- Margin = 10.88
Year = 2 (730.4844days) --- Month = 13 (383.8977days) --- Margin = 18.66
Year = 2 (730.4844days) --- Month = 14 (413.4283days) --- Margin = 317.06
Year = 2 (730.4844days) --- Month = 15 (442.9589days) --- Margin = 287.53
...
Year = 18 (6574.3596days) --- Month = 219 (6467.1992days) --- Margin = 107.16
Year = 18 (6574.3596days) --- Month = 220 (6496.7298days) --- Margin = 77.63
Year = 18 (6574.3596days) --- Month = 221 (6526.2604days) --- Margin = 48.1
Year = 18 (6574.3596days) --- Month = 222 (6555.791days) --- Margin = 18.57
Year = 19 (6939.6018days) --- Month = 223 (6585.3216days) --- Margin = 10.96
Year = 19 (6939.6018days) --- Month = 224 (6614.8522days) --- Margin = 324.75
Year = 19 (6939.6018days) --- Month = 225 (6644.3828days) --- Margin = 295.22
Year = 19 (6939.6018days) --- Month = 226 (6673.9133days) --- Margin = 265.69
Year = 19 (6939.6018days) --- Month = 227 (6703.4439days) --- Margin = 236.16
Year = 19 (6939.6018days) --- Month = 228 (6732.9745days) --- Margin = 206.63
Year = 19 (6939.6018days) --- Month = 229 (6762.5051days) --- Margin = 177.1
Year = 19 (6939.6018days) --- Month = 230 (6792.0357days) --- Margin = 147.57
Year = 19 (6939.6018days) --- Month = 231 (6821.5663days) --- Margin = 118.04
Year = 19 (6939.6018days) --- Month = 232 (6851.0969days) --- Margin = 88.5
Year = 19 (6939.6018days) --- Month = 233 (6880.6275days) --- Margin = 58.97
Year = 19 (6939.6018days) --- Month = 234 (6910.1581days) --- Margin = 29.44
Year = 19 (6939.6018days) --- Month = 235 (6939.6887days) --- Margin = 0.09
```